# How to make file validation

Tags: javascript, validation, file-upload

I already create this script :

```
function validate(f)

    {

    var fname="txt_nama";
    var fld=document.getElementById(fname);

    var fup1 = document.getElementById('file_id');
    var fileName1 = fup1.value;
    var ext1 = fileName1.substring(fileName1.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    var file1 = fup1.files;

    var fup2 = document.getElementById('file_foto');
    var fileName2 = fup2.value;
    var ext2 = fileName2.substring(fileName2.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    var file2 = fup2.files;

    var email_re = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/i;
    if(fld.value == "")
            {      
            alert("Please enter your name");
            fld.focus();
            return false;
            }      


    else if(f.txt_email.value == "")
            {
            alert("Please enter your email address.");
            f.txt_email.focus();
            return false;                                  
            }

    else if (!email_re.test(f.txt_email.value))
            {
            alert("Invalid E-mail address.");
            f.txt_email.focus();
            return false;
            }      

    else if(fup1.value == "")
            {      
            alert("Please enter your Scan identity");
            fup1.focus();
            return false;
            }      

    else if(ext1 != 'jpg' || ext1 != 'GIF' || ext1 != 'JPEG' || ext1 != 'jpeg' || ext1 != 'gif' || ext1 !=       'JPG' || ext1 != 'png' || ext1 != 'PNG')
            {
            alert("Upload images with extention JPG, PNG, or GIF only");
            fup1.focus();
            return false;
            }

    else if(file1.size>200000)
            {
            alert("Max size of Scan data is 200Kb");
            fup1.focus();
            return false;                                                  
            }

    else if(fup2.value == "")
            {      
            alert("Please enter your Photo");
            fup2.focus();
            return false;
            }

    else if(ext2 != 'jpg' || ext2 != 'GIF' || ext2 != 'JPEG' || ext2 != 'jpeg' || ext2 != 'gif' || ext2 != 'JPG' || ext2 != 'png' || ext2 != 'PNG')
            {
            alert("Upload images with extention JPG, PNG, or GIF only");
            fup2.focus();
            return false;
            }

    else if(file2.size>200000)
            {
            alert("Max size of Scan data is 200Kb");
            fup2.focus();
            return false;                                          
            }      


    else{

            return true;}

    }
```

I got a problem in file upload validation,
when I enter right extention of file it is still false or still validating,
did I do some mistake in if-else?

Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using AND, not OR, when testing the extensions:

```
else if(ext1 != 'jpg' && ext1 != 'GIF' && ext1 != 'JPEG' && ext1 != 'jpeg' && ext1 != 'gif' && ext1 !=  'JPG' && ext1 != 'png' && ext1 != 'PNG')
```

OR is true if any of the arguments is true. So if the extension is `jpg`, then `ext1 != 'GIF'` will be true, so the whole test will be true.

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar said, your condition is wrong.

In the future, try to debug the code. Either run it the debugger of your browser (see the manual / docs how to start it) or add `console.log()` in a few places like so:

```
        var fup1 = document.getElementById('file_id');
        var fileName1 = fup1.value;
        var ext1 = fileName1.substring(fileName1.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        var file1 = fup1.files;

        console.log([fup1, fileName1, ext1]);
```

That will put the objects on your browser's console where you can examine them to see whether they contain what you expect.

Comment: Good general advice, although I don't think any amount of `console.log()` will help find this particular bug.

Comment: He could log the whole condition.

Comment: That still won't tell him why it's not giving the answer he expects. If he doesn't understand boolean logic, no amount of logging will fix that. At least he didn't write `ext1 != "jpg" || "gif" || "JPEG"` like I've seen in other questions. :)